# Why are image borders and extra padding showing up in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, border, padding

I built and tested my site in Firefox but now when wanting to launch I realized that there is extra padding showing up between the menu and posts as well as borders on some of the images when viewed in IE9.

I have looked through all of the CSS and can't figure out what might be causing either of these problems. Any ideas would be great.

Here is the site: http://beautyintheweeds.com

Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI... you have many, many improperly nested/unclosed tags... you should really clean them up (if you do a View-source in Firefox it will highlight all the incorrect nesting/tags in red for you)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up... I am still a beginner for sure. can you tell me what is wrong with a few of those marked in red?

Comment: tag nesting must be uniform... if you open 3 tags... a, b, c... then you must close them in the same (but reverse) order (c, b, a). the break tag should be in this format `<br/>` and there should be a space between all of your attributes (I noticed some links without spaces).

Comment: Open your page in Firefox. Right click and choose 'View Source' - Its source viewer shows you the markup errors in red.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has different default css rules. Use a css reset to bring everything to the same defaults.

Comment: This is sort of like cutting a birthday cake with a chainsaw.  Oh sure, it works and slices the cake but isn't the precise tool/answer to the problem.  In this case I think inspecting the padding on the elements the OP is struggling with and tracing the styles is more applicable.

Comment: then do it. and my answer is the exact answer to the question why a different browser shows different margins and image borders.

Comment: I tried a CSS reset and it fixed the borders around the images but not the padding.